# No error messages but my login is not working

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, authentication

This is the checklogin.php page. The whole idea is that based on your status (1 or 0) the program should guide you to the right page (red_form or yellow_form). At the moment this code will let me to login no matter who I am (not in database) or then will let me to login as a person from the database, but won't guide me correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    require_once "connection.php";
    session_start();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $username= $_POST['username'];
                $password= sha1($_POST['password']);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM information WHERE username = '$username' AND password 
='$password'";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                if($result){
                    echo "Yippii";

                } else {
                    echo "Error";
                }
                $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
                if($rowcount > 0){
                    echo "Uspw ok";
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['status'] = $row['status'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                    echo $_SESSION['username'];
                    echo $_SESSION['id'];
                    if($_SESSION['status'] == "1"){
                        header('Location: red_form.php');
                    } else {
                        header('Location: yellow_form.php');
                    }  
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: so there is valid SQL but it's just outright wrong? debug!

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: this shouldn't be used in a live environment. It's for academic purposes I hope, right?

Comment: You should check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way to verify that everything with the query is working as it should.

Comment: ...and php error reporting.

Comment: There are too many unknowns here. The form and the schema and if you did use the same algo during the insertion. You should also add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: Note: You should place `session_start();` on top of your required file. Should that error out for some reason, you stand at outputting before header.

Comment: `$username= $_POST['username']; $password= sha1($_POST['password']); $sql = "SELECT * FROM information WHERE username = '$username' AND password 
='$password'";` ... *\*le sigh\** ... kill it with fire and start over with a modern tutorial, it's your only hope.

Comment: Don't use SHA1 for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: If you print something header('Location:...); no works.

remove this and try...
if($result){
    echo "Yippii";

   } else {
    echo "Error";
}
..
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo $_SESSION['id'];

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner this is only for schooling, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

You have given "else" condition in the wrong place. Your login is working fine, You can follow the code,

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $username= $_POST['username'];
            $password= sha1($_POST['password']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM chklogin WHERE username = '$username' AND password 
='$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if($result){
                echo "Yippie";

            } else {
                echo "Error";
            }

            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
            echo ($rowcount);

            if($rowcount > 0)
            {
                echo "Uspw ok";
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['status'] = $row['status'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                $_SESSION['login'] = true;

                echo $_SESSION['username'];
                echo $_SESSION['id'];

                if($_SESSION['status'] == "1"){
                    header('Location: red_form.php');
                }  
            }
            else
            {
                header('Location: yellow_form.php');
            }
        }
    ?>

      <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="enter password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```